# Return Elements of Vector by Row Number

Tags: r, vector

I would like to return element of a vector by row number.

If I have the following vector:

```r
OriginalVector <- c("The nimble red fox", "Lazy Grey Dog", "Red Fox funny")
```

I would like to return "Lazy Grey Dog" only using a row reference.

Comment: ```x[2]``` this is a basic of R so you may want to look at tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `[` operator:

```
OriginalVector[2]
[1] "Lazy Grey Dog"
```